# Custom UIView class with blur

Tags: swift, uiview, blur

I am trying to create a custom UIView class that I can change the class for some views in my app. I want the view to be round and have the blur effect. I can get it to work via func that specifically references the outlet name but would like to just change the class of the view so it is reuseable.

```
import UIKit

class RoundedBlur: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addRoundedBlur()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addRoundedBlur()
    }

    func addRoundedBlur() {
        let roundedBlurView = UIView()

        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light))
        blur.frame = roundedBlurView.bounds
        blur.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * roundedBlurView.bounds.size.width
        blur.clipsToBounds = true

        blur.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        roundedBlurView.insertSubview(blur, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: So... what's the issue?

Comment: So... what's UIVisualEffectView?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a subview to achieve this.
You can just reference the class itself, this way you can create new views by extending reusing this one.

```java
class RoundedBlur: UIView {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addRoundedBlur()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.addRoundedBlur()
  }

  func addRoundedBlur() {
    let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light))
    self.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    self.clipsToBounds = true

    blur.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.insertSubview(blur, at: 0)

  }
}
```